# ClearValue does not restore pre-set value

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I'm trying to reset the Background property of a button after I change it dynamically.

---

```
<Button Canvas.Left="-1" Canvas.Top="0" Content="a" FontFamily="Arial" Grid.Column="1" Height="60" Tag="a" Name="Ba" Width="60" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="35" Foreground="Black">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF757575" Offset="0.893" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF989898" Offset="0.074" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
```

---

After I use the ClearValue method like so:

---

```
Ba.ClearValue(System.Windows.Controls.Button.BackgroundProperty);
```

---

I doesn't quite go back to what is defined in the .xaml file. it looks similar, but not the same. Looks like some information is lost.

How can I, in some way, store all that information so it can be restored completely?

Thanks in advance,

Francisco Santiago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a Style, set the Background there and reapply it if you need it again.

Comment: I'll try this one and I'll get back to you. Thank you H.B.

Comment: @FranciscoSantiago: Be aware of [precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) though. e.g. if you set a value on a control it will override the style.

Comment: Well, I was blindly trying to find my way into this App, because I don't have much time. 

By defining this style and applying it to all buttons, not only ClearValue resets the style correctly, but I just erased about 300 lines of code. 

Thank you so much Master H.B.

Comment: And the ClearValue method was indeed reseting the style to the default WPF style for Button controls.

Answer (score 0):

> I doesn't quite go back to what is defined in the .xaml file

It's not supposed to; `ClearValue` clears the local value of the property, making it "unset". When the value is needed, it is determined according to the precedence rules described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx). In most cases it will be the value declared in the control's default style.

If you want to restore the original value defined in XAML, you need to store it somewhere before you change it

Comment: Not quite, it goes back to unset and resolves to whatever is defined in styles and default template.

Comment: I'll try creating a new style. I'm sorry for the noob question. I'm completely new to WPF.